# Is a static member function visible inside a templated class before it is declared?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, static-members, requires-clause

Should static member function `b` be visible to the requires-clause of the default constructor of `s`? What does the C++20 standard say about the legality of the provided example?

```
template<auto...>
struct s {
    s() requires (s::b()) = default; // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
    static constexpr bool b()
    { return true; }
};
static_assert((s<>{}, true));
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zf3q14T76)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:3:22: error: no member named 'b' in 's<...>'
    3 |     s() requires (s::b()) = default;
      |                   ~~~^
<source>:7:15: error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant
expression
    7 | static_assert((s<>{}, true));
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:16: note: non-constexpr constructor 's' cannot be used in a constant
expression
    7 | static_assert((s<>{}, true));
      |                ^
<source>:3:5: note: declared here
    3 |     s() requires (s::b()) = default;
      |     ^
```

Comment: There are actually a lot of duplicates for this.

Comment: Related(if not dupe) [constexpr not working if the function is declared inside class scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493652/constexpr-not-working-if-the-function-is-declared-inside-class-scope). Also see [Why can't I use the result of a static constexpr in the declaration of another function in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799393/why-cant-i-use-the-result-of-a-static-constexpr-in-the-declaration-of-another-f)

Comment: [member function bodies are evaluated only once the class has been completely defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37194551/12002570)

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, that answer gives a great insight in what likely happens under the hood of the compiler but it doesn't address any formal standardese, which is what I'm specifically asking for.

Comment: Also [Error using a constexpr as a template parameter within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108314/error-using-a-constexpr-as-a-template-parameter-within-the-same-class). So one of them should be closes as a dupe of the other and the new answer should be posted there/here.

Comment: Here is one more explanation/dupe: [the definition of the static member function `b` is not complete until the end of the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76639029/12002570)

Comment: And [constexpr function call doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777610/constexpr-function-call-doesnt-compile) and [Static member access in constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995196/static-member-access-in-constant-expressions)

Comment: @user12002570 The fact that `s` is a template actually is relevant and the linked questions do not consider that.

Comment: @user17732522 The [first dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785821/12002570) that I linked in the dupe list?

Comment: @user12002570 In that one the use is in a complete-class context and also separately instantiated, while that isn't the case here. The question here is one of lookup rules in templates, maybe specifics of instantiation of requires-clauses, not just about the definition of the `constexpr` function.

Comment: @user17732522 I see. I remember asking this mysefl or atleast answering this, but couldn't find that post anymore.

Comment: @user17732522 I think it is ill-formed because "an invocation of an undefined constexpr function" is not a constant expression? Also the invocation is not in the complete class context.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the member name `b` will not be found because `b` is declared after the point where it's named, and the *requires-clause* is not a complete-class context. [[class.mem.general]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#7) defines the set of complete-class contexts, and [[class.member.lookup]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#3) explains which class members can be found during name lookup:

> The declaration set is the result of a single search in the scope of *C* for *N* from immediately after the *class-specifier* of *C* if *P* is in a complete-class context of *C* or from *P* otherwise. If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains *C* itself, and calculation is complete.

Since the *requires-clause* isn't a complete-class context, a single search is done from the point where `b` is named. The declaration of `b` doesn't precede that point, so it isn't found by the single search ([[basic.lookup.general]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#3)).

Complicating this analysis is the fact that templates can contain dependent names, and those dependent names are subject to different rules. However, `s::b` is not a dependent name because its lookup context refers to the current instantiation. See [[temp.dep.type]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#5):

> A qualified name ([basic.lookup.qual]) is dependent if
>
> - it is a *conversion-function-id* whose *conversion-type-id* is dependent, or
> - its lookup context is dependent and is not the current instantiation, or
> - its lookup context is the current instantiation and it is `operator=`, or
> - its lookup context is the current instantiation and has at least one dependent base class, and qualified name lookup for the name finds nothing ([basic.lookup.qual]).

These are basically the circumstances under which the name lookup would need to be deferred until instantiation time. In this case, because the lookup context is the current instantiation `s`, name lookup for `b` doesn't need to be deferred unless the declaration that it would find is potentially in a dependent base class (in which case you need to know the template arguments before you can know whether `b` is in a base class or not). In this case `s::b` is not a dependent name because there are no base classes. Name lookup for non-dependent names is not deferred under [[temp.res.general]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#1). So it finds nothing (because it's not in a complete-class context) and the program is ill-formed.

So I think GCC and MSVC have a bug here, although because name lookup in templates is such a tricky issue, it's possible that there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score -2):

The behavior(ill-formed) of the program can be understood using [expr.const#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5) which states:

> **5.** An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> **5.2** **an invocation of an undefined constexpr function**;

(emphasis mine)

And since at the point of the invocation of `s::b()`, the static `constexpr` function is undefined, the expression `s::b()` is not a constant expression at that point. Combine this with the fact that the context where the invocation is used is not a [complete class context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general), we get the mentioned error.

> A **complete-class context** of a class is a
>
> - function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument
> - noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class.

---

Thus, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: If at the point where `s` is instantiated the function `s::b` can already be found by lookup, then its definition is also already available, since it is located before the point of instantiation in the template definition. If lookup doesn't even find `s::b` (as Clang's error message states), then the quote is irrelevant. Imagine it was `requires (decltype(s::b()){true})` instead. Would that be valid? It doesn't require a `constexpr` function call.

Comment: @user17732522 You said that "then its definition is also already available". But I don't think this is necessarily true as the definitions of member function only get instantiated when they(the member function) are used.

Comment: @Alan "_invocation of an undefined constexpr function_" is a bit vague, but it can't mean that the point-of-instantiation of the `constexpr` function should be before the point of use, because the point-of-instantiation of a function will always be _after_ the first use that causes implicit instantiation. That would make `constexpr` templated functions unusable in practice. It can only refer to the point-of-definition instead.